# Entry in mongod.log for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am seeing these lines every second in my mongod.log and I was wondering what is causing it.

"[journal] journal REMAPPRIVATEVIEW done startedAt: 1 n:2 0ms
 [journal] journal REMAPPRIVATEVIEW done startedAt: 3 n:2 0ms"

Thanks,

Sandra Arnold

Answer (score 1):

Those log lines are related to Mongo's journaling. MongoDB uses journaling to help ensure data integrity by tracking what was (or in the case of a system failure, what should have been) done.

You can learn more about Mongo's journaling here:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/journaling/
and
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-journaling/